# change text style inline in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to put two words in a figure, using `ax.text` or `fig.text`. The problem is that the first word should be written in bold and italic, the second without any particular style. For example

***one*** two

The two words should be written as if they are in the same sentence. I can use two calls to `ax.text`, but I would like to avoid to set manually the alignment between the two labels. What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib allows you to use latex. It is not enabled by default, so you have to activate it first.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# activate usage of latex
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

# generate a simple graph
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(6,3))
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, r"\textit{\textbf{one}} two (on the axes)")
fig.text(1., 1., r"\textit{\textbf{one}} two (on the figure)",
        horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='top')

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @RuggeroTurra does that answer your question?

Comment: more or less: is it possible without latex?

Comment: Except for the solution with multiple text elements that you proposed in the question, I don't think so. For that matplotlib would need to support some sort of markup text with which you could encode the formatting in the string (basically what latex does).

Comment: matplotlib has its own (limited) latex interpreter built-in. Mainly intended to support `'$...$'` math text stuff, I think it also supports some basic latex notations.