# get bounding box of a text and update the canvas

Tags: matplotlib

Similarly as in this question [change text style inline in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890831/change-text-style-inline-in-matplotlib) I want to write two labels in different styles (bold and normal, e.g. "**bold** normal") as if they were the same label without using latex.

Here something that it is working:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def print_label(fig):
    l = fig.text(0.5, 0.5, "bold", fontweight='bold')
    def on_draw(event):
        xmax = l.get_window_extent().inverse_transformed(fig.transFigure).max[0]
        print xmax
        fig.text(xmax, 0.5, "Normal")
        return False
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', on_draw)

print_label(fig)
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.show()
```

but I am not happy since the usage of `print_label` is not transparent: the user has to call `fig.canvas.draw()`. So I tried this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def print_label(fig):
    l = fig.text(0.5, 0.5, "bold", fontweight='bold')
    def on_draw(event):
        xmax = l.get_window_extent().inverse_transformed(fig.transFigure).max[0]
        print xmax
        fig.text(xmax, 0.5, "Normal")
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(event)
        fig.canvas.draw()
        return False
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', on_draw)

print_label(fig)
plt.show()
```

the problem there is that I am not able to disconnect the event, and I am getting:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the first section of: http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def print_label(fig):
    l = fig.text(0.5, 0.5, "bold", fontweight='bold')
    def on_draw(event):
        xmax = l.get_window_extent().inverse_transformed(fig.transFigure).max[0]
        print xmax
        fig.text(xmax, 0.5, "Normal")
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
        return False
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', on_draw)
    fig.canvas.draw()

print_label(fig)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `RuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o renderer` in case someone gets this error when trying to call `l.get_window_extent().inverse_transformed(fig.transFigure)`. Call `plt.gcf().canvas.draw()` before to solve it.